# Is there a way to exclude a network interface from being bound via INADDR_ANY?

Tags: linux, tcp, udp, network-security

In network programming, it's common to pass `INADDR_ANY` (or `IN6ADDR_ANY`) as part of the second argument to [bind()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), telling the networking stack that you want the socket to receive connections/traffic from any network interface that the machine happens to have.  Many programs do this, as it is often the most useful behavior.  The other common option is to specify a single network interface to bind to, instead.

However, I have a use-case where I'd like one particular network interface on my Linux machine be "reserved", in the sense that it is not included in the set of network interfaces used by sockets bound to `INADDR_ANY`.  In particular, I'd like this network interface to be usable only by sockets that have bound themselves to its IP address explicitly (or perhaps have performed some other explicit step to indicate that they are aware of this network interface's special status and wish to use it anyway) -- sort of a "socket whitelist", if you will, to guarantee that only a few hand-picked apps can send/receive traffic over this network interface.  (These apps will likely be ones I wrote and personally control, if that matters)

Is there any mechanism to accomplish this in Linux?

Some approaches that I have considered but am not entirely satisfied with:

1. Modifying all apps to bind explicitly to the network interfaces they want to use, instead of binding to `INADDR_ANY`, and not including this network interface in the set.   (too much work, and I probably don't have access to modify all such apps anyway)
2. Setting up a firewall on the network interface such that only traffic on certain ports is accepted.  (this might sort-of work, but it means I have to specify in advance all ports that I will use on the interface, which precludes software that required dynamic port allocation... and of course there would still be the chance that some unexpected app gets "lucky" and happens to bind to one of the whitelisted ports, which would be undesirable)
3. Switch to SELinux or similar security-oriented distribution that has fine-grained ACLs (not a realistic option here, for various reasons I won't get into)

Comment: *" I have a use-case where I'd like one particular network interface on my Linux machine be "reserved""* - please be more clear about this use case. Currently it looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me where you want an unspecified problem (X) with a specific approach (Y) and thus ask on how to do Y. Maybe one can up with a better idea once X is known too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the Y is that a customer wants to attach our headless server device to a network where only 'highly secured' devices are permitted, which is to say that the only traffic they want our device to respond to on that network is the customer-facing service that customer explicitly wants to use; all the other services on the device should be verifiably unable to communicate over that network interface.  (The other services still need to run and communicate via the other/non-secure-network interfaces though, as these servers can be clustered together and need to talk to each other)

Comment: This kind of requirement is traditionally solved with firewall rules, i.e. everything is blocked except this kind of service. An alternative or addition would be to expose the network card directly to the specific container or VM where the customer facing application is running,  and not have it usable (no address assigned) for the rest of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried or considered iptables (I know its hard to specify precisely the requirements, but it is probably worth trying and trying until success ):

To allow traffic only from IP address 10.0.0.1 and port 80 to be forwarded to the reserved network interface

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i <reserved_interface> -s 10.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And then block all other

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i <reserved_interface> -j DROP
```

Or to use the network-manager to create a virtual network interface and move the IP address you want to reserve to the virtual interface, this way the applications will not be able to bind to it by default, you can also use firewall rules on the virtual interface. I will watch this article to see what will the final result.